# How do I know what width / height I should set on an image on a responsive site?

Tags: css, performance, image-size

I feel like a noob for asking this, but here goes :)

I'm reading about [Google's AMP](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/get_started/about-amp.html) and how you have to define the width and height of images to reduce page render time.

**Scenario 1 (using AMP)**
Let's say I want to use the entire width of the mobile screen, but I want it to scale correctly. How do I find and set the height / width? And how do I know the width of the mobile screen?
***Update*** Using e.g. WP, you can have it scale images to 3 different sizes. But the browser still doesn't know what size the user has selected to use in the article untill the image has loaded (ok, I see a workaround for WP).

**Scenario 2 (for normal webpage)**
A user in a CMS may upload images in different sizes and different formats. When using the images in an article, I want to have correct aspect ratio. How do I know when is what?

I don't know the size of the image until it's loaded. So how can I set the images height / width attributes?

Do we have to assume that I know beforehand the size of the image, and based on that, use the correct height / width to maintain correct aspect ratio depending on the screen view size?

***Update*** 
The best solution, as far as I see, is that one could load image meta data before loading the image file. Doing a DB request is (hopefully) quicker than loading the actual image.

Comment: Scenario 1 -- use javascript -- Scenario 2 -- convert and compress the images to the predefined smaller size  on the server prior to displaying them to speed up things. as for the aspect ratio, that's what css is for, you can also do that on the server as i mentioned before

Answer (score 0):

Best way imo, is to reduce the weight of the images on the server side. Then, you'll know the height and the width. You can do this dinamically via AJAX if you need too.

To set the correct width and height in CSS (from Bootstrap's img-responsive class) :

```
display: block;
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
```

Comment: By doing this, you are still not telling the browser how big the image is and it needs to calculatethe size once the image has loaded. You have to set the height / width in the `<img>` tag so the browser knows how much space is needed for the image.

Answer (score -1):

Just add `width:100%;` or `height:50%;` in your css file depending on your needs

Comment: You probably got down voted because all you have done now, is setting all images half it's height - and the browser still has no idea of the height / width of the image.